# Read from file in c++ till end of line?

Tags: c++, file, line

How can i read data untill end of line?I have a text file "file.txt" with this

```
1 5 9 2 59 4 6
2 1 2 
3 2 30 1 55
```

I have this code:

```
ifstream file("file.txt",ios::in);
while(!file.eof())
{
    ....//my functions(1)
    while(?????)//Here i want to write :while (!end of file)
    {
        ...//my functions(2)
    }

}
```

in my functions(2) i use the data from the lines and it need to be Int ,not char

Comment: Why do you need to read until the end of the line? And by "end of the line" do you mean the end of the *first* line, or the end of all the lines?

Comment: by "end of line" i mean read the first line,use the numbers to do what i have to and go on the second line...,then on the third line until the end of the file

Comment: Are you performing the same operations on each line?

Comment: Do any of the current answers help? Please give feedback.

Comment: No,they don't help.
the code which herohuyongtao writes works incorrect.
i will repeat:i want to take one by one the elemnts from the 1st line till the end and do operations with them.
Then i do the same thing and same operations with the 2nd line ....

Comment: On the contrary, what you described is *extactly* what herohuyongtao's code does. Maybe you should explain what you believe his example does incorrectly?

Comment: I would like to submit an answer, but first I need to know more information about what you're trying to do. herohuyongtao's answer goes through each line and then uses a string stream to iterate over the integers of that line. If that isn't satisfactory for you, I would need to have more detail on what's trying to be done.

Comment: @0x499602D2 herohuyongtao's answer is returning random values
i take the elements one by one and the result is 1 2 3 2 30 1 55 1...
how is this happening?i think it must have another solution

Comment: [The example here](http://ideone.com/aHUR3X) shows that his code is working as expected. Does the code posted there differ from your code?

Answer (score 12):

Don't use `while(!file.eof())` as `eof()` will only be set after reading the end of the file. It does not indicate, that the next read will be the end of the file. You can use `while(getline(...))` instead and combine with `istringstream` to read numbers.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// ... ...
ifstream file("file.txt",ios::in);
if (file.good())
{
    string str;
    while(getline(file, str)) 
    {
        istringstream ss(str);
        int num;
        while(ss >> num)
        {
            // ... you now get a number ...
        }
    }
}
```

You need to read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: if i use getline i have to convert from int to char,but i need the data to be int!!!!

Comment: (getline(file, str)) is not working
error:can;t  convert from istream to char

Comment: Error 1 error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::getline(_Elem *,std::streamsize)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::ifstream' to 'char *'

Comment: @user3050163 It shoud run OK, I just tested it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Ailm6T).

Comment: @herohuyongtao it run,but the result is wrong.
it mixed the numbers from the three lines

Comment: @user3050163 Then do something for each `getline()` to split them up.

Answer (score 2):

As for reading until the end of the line. there's [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

You have another problem though, and that is that you loop `while (!file.eof())` which will most likely not work as you expect. The reason is that the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the file. Instead you should do e.g. `while (std::getline(...))`.

Comment: @user3050163 Read into a `std::string`, put in a `std::istringstream`, loop using the input operator `>>` to get each whitespace-delimited value.

Comment: @user3050163 Or after you read the line and put it in an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to put the values directly into a [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) using [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Answer (score 1):

```
char eoln(fstream &stream)          // C++ code Return End of Line
{
    if (stream.eof()) return 1;     // True end of file
    long curpos;    char ch;
    curpos = stream.tellp();        // Get current position
    stream.get(ch);                 // Get next char
    stream.clear();                 // Fix bug in VC 6.0
    stream.seekp(curpos);           // Return to prev position
    if ((int)ch != 10)              // if (ch) eq 10
        return 0;                   // False not end of row (line)
    else                            // (if have spaces?)
        stream.get(ch);             // Go to next row
    return 1;                       // True end of row (line)
}                                   // End function
```

Comment: You can use this to read until the rest of the line:  string line;getline(stream, line); . I use it to read the remaining part of the file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it as function in order to call some where, you can use a vector. This is a function which I use to read such file and return integers element wise.

```
vector<unsigned long long> Hash_file_read(){
    int frames_sec = 25;
    vector<unsigned long long> numbers;
    ifstream my_file("E:\\Sanduni_projects\\testing\\Hash_file.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
    if (my_file) {

        //ifstream file;
        string line;

        for (int i = 0; i < frames_sec; i++){
            getline(my_file, line);
            numbers.push_back(stoull(line));
        }

    }
    else{
        cout << "File can not be opened" << endl;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```